# Query is not working in Impala

Tags: hiveql, impala

```
(SELECT CONCAT('ABCDE',SUM((SELECT MAX(id) FROM optigo_data.admin_userdetails LIMIT 1)+1)))
```

Above is working in Mysql but its not working in Impala/Hive, please help me out.

> Error: sub query is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this error is that Impala only supports subqueries in the FROM and WHERE clause.
I think this would be the impala equivalent:

```
SELECT
CONCAT('ABCDE',cast(SUM(t.value+1) as string))
from 
    (SELECT MAX(cast(id as int)) as value 
    FROM optigo_data.admin_userdetails LIMIT 1) as t
```

But looking at the query assuming your goal is to produce a string containing the highest ID + 1, a simpler solution would be:

```
SELECT
CONCAT('ABCDE',cast(MAX(cast(id as int)+1) as string))
FROM optigo_data.admin_userdetails
```

Please correct me if my assumption is incorrect. You can drop the `cast as int` if `id` is already in numeric format.